# Hello i'm having some linux kubuntu problems

Tags: kubuntu, kde

Hello im new to linux and im having some difficulties here:

- The application menu is too big How can i resize it?
- How can i create an link file of an webpage in my folder?
  i try to create new file in URL type, and i paste the link in it
  then i have to click open with browser, then the browser opens just a black screen with nothing. The top bar doesn't shows https askubuntu it show just the file path. Do i am unable to create url files?
- I tried to install steam but i got error message: Couldn't set up the Steam Runtime. Are you running low on disk space?
  Continuing...
  You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
  libXtst.so.6
  libXrandr.so.2
  libXi.so.6
  libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
  libpipewire-0.3.so.0
  libbz2.so.1.0
  But it did loaded. But when it load it takes a few time to open. The errors messages just appeared at 2 first times. Do i need to just keep or i need to do something? i could login
- Why is my custom mouse cursor changes in other tabs?
- Can i install BeamNG? i have it on steam it needs wine right?
- Also the the icon games in the app menu are blank

Thanks for helping. Sorry for asking a lot of questions.

Comment: One question at a time!

Comment: Try the Search box at the top of the page. Some of those questions have already been answered previously.

Comment: Please don't edit the question every a few seconds with adding new questions. This is a question and answer site. A question should be ONE question. Otherwise it will be closed.

Comment: **ONLY post one question at a time**.  We do NOT allow more than one question that have nothing to do with each other in a single question.  Please read the guidelines of how to post that you get in the "new question" page before posting again.  I have locked this due to the volume of edits you've made to add more and more questions and disregarding the fact that we have all said "post only one question at a time"